# Can i use this database wrapper class for connecting more than two databases

Tags: php, database, connection, pdo

I am using this database wrapper class http://www.ajaxray.com/blog/2009/08/29/simple-php-pdo-wrapper-light-static-easy-to-use/

Can i use this Database wrapper class for taking data from one database and insert to other .

If yes then how should i use it ?

e.g. i want to execute following query .

```
echo $select_resellerData = "select * from resellerDetailsEntry where date_format(updatedon,'%Y-%m-%d')='".$date_var.str_pad($i, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT)."'";

        $fetch = querytobeexecutedfrom_A_Db($select_resellerData);

         while($row_reseller = mysql_fetch_array($fetch))
         {
            //echo $row_reseller['alloctype'];
            ##-------------------------------------------Insert into reseller dashboard for each reseller-------------------------------##
            $insert_into ="insert into tbl_reseller_dashboard_intermediate set
            firstname ='".$row_reseller['firstname']."',
            lastname ='".$row_reseller['lastname']."',
            mobile ='".$row_reseller['mobile']."',
            email ='".$row_reseller['email']."',
            citybelongsto ='".$row_reseller['citybelongsto']."',
            cityoptedfor ='".$row_reseller['cityoptedfor']."',
            tmecode ='".$row_reseller['tmecode']."',
            tmename ='".$row_reseller['tmename']."',
            updatedon ='".$row_reseller['updatedon']."',
            apptype ='".$row_reseller['apptype']."',
            empparent='".$row_reseller['data_city']."',


            entrydate ='".$date_var.str_pad($i, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT)."'";

            $run=querytobeexecutedfrom_B_Db($insert_into);
         }
```

How querytobeexecutedfrom_A_Db and querytobeexecutedfrom_B_Db will be executed with the use of this database wrapper class?

Comment: another database or another table?

Comment: also you have to escape values using mysql_real_escape_string

Comment: Another Host and DB means Completely Different connection ..

Comment: http://refactormycode.com/codes/1077-pdo-database-wrapper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot do this, because the wrapper you use uses a static function to assign the current database. This means that inside the wrapper you set a variable that sets your database and that variable doesn't change if you create another instance of the wrapper. To solve this you need to change the wrapper (if you know what you're doing) or use another wrapper.

Comment: Please  Suggest another better Wrapper ? Or the Change in this wrapper ?

Comment: Changing the wrapper is not so easy. I usually make one myself, but this one looks fine: [wrapper](http://www.ricocheting.com/code/php/mysql-database-class-wrapper)

Comment: But this one is not using PDO.

Comment: I want to use PDO is it ok ? Do you know any PDO Wrapper ?